# All my files and pictures got lost or deleted while installing the OS X El Capitan software

Tags: macbook-pro, backup, photos.app, storage

All my files and pictures got lost or deleted while installing the OS X El Capitan software! Is there a way to get at least my iPhoto Library back? I have not made a back up before.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: All your photos should still be in the Photos application.  If not there, do a complete shut-down and restart.  Sometimes they take a little bit of time to show up.  See [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7255287?tstart=0).

Comment: You should really have made a backup before upgrading the software.

Comment: I cannot give you the full path but your iPhotos library would have been renamed and a copy should have been made to use with Photos.app.

If I remember correctly the iPhotos Library  gets an extension added to it .migratedphotolibrary

Answer (score 1):

You can try a recovery software like wondershare recovery data or Disk Drill (i think you can download free trial), Those soft will be able to detect lost data (even deleted). There are many other soft you can test, but those two are great !

Hope this will help,

Peace

Answer (score 0):

See ur recycle bin icon it might  be there